# How to Process requests one by one in flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, flask, process

I'm developing an application that sends data to the flask back end. Then the flask inserts the received into elastic search. Before inserting to elastic search it will check whether the id is existing or not.If the id exists it update or else it will insert to the index.

Sample code :

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import  jsonify, request
import jwt
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/test',methods=['POST'])
def hello():       
    try:         
        id  = request.form['id']
        database = "sample"
        es =Elasticsearch("localhost",port = 9200)
        cols=es.search(index=database,  body={ "query": {  "match": { "id": id}}})
        present =False
        if cols['hits']['hits']:
            x1=cols['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']
            eid = cols['hits']['hits'][0]['_id']
            present =True        
        if present == False:                          
            newvalues = {"url":"hello",'id':id}
            es.index(index=database, doc_type="logs", body=newvalues)      
        else: #if already there append data                        
            newvalues ={}                           
            es.update(index=database,doc_type='logs',id=eid,body={"doc":newvalues})            
        return jsonify({'status': 'success'})
    except jwt.InvalidTokenError  as e:
        print(e)
        return jsonify({'success': 'false', 'message': 'Invalid Token!!!'})
if  __name__=="__main__":
    try:
        app.run(host="localhost",port=5005,debug=True,processes =1)
    except Exception as e:
        print("exception in test",e)
```

The problem here is, the requests are sending for every 5 seconds from the front end. So it conflicts sometimes,(ie) whenever a request is received with the id and at the same time the insertion process of the id takes place. The second request assumes that the id is not present in the database so it also inserts which turns 2 data with the same id in the index. What should I do to insert one at a time and the other should wait?

python - 3.6

**Edited :
Tried using semaphore :**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import  jsonify, request
import jwt
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import threading
sLock = threading.Semaphore()
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/test',methods=['POST'])
def hello(): 
    sLock.acquire()  
    try:         
        id  = request.form['id']
        database = "sample"
        es =Elasticsearch("localhost",port = 9200)
        cols=es.search(index=database,  body={ "query": {  "match": { "id": id}}})
        present =False
        if cols['hits']['hits']:
            x1=cols['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']
            eid = cols['hits']['hits'][0]['_id']
            present =True        
        if present == False:                          
            newvalues = {"url":"hello",'id':id}
            es.index(index=database, doc_type="logs", body=newvalues)      
        else: #if already there append data                        
            newvalues ={}                           
            es.update(index=database,doc_type='logs',id=eid,body={"doc":newvalues})
        sLock.release()            
        return jsonify({'status': 'success'})
    except jwt.InvalidTokenError  as e:
        print(e)
        return jsonify({'success': 'false', 'message': 'Invalid Token!!!'})
if  __name__=="__main__":
    try:
        app.run(host="localhost",port=5005,debug=True,processes =1)
    except Exception as e:
        print("exception in test",e)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of concurrency. Preventing concurrent access to a shared resource is usually done using [locks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes i tried using semaphores but it allow only the first request and blocks all the others even though the first was completed.

Comment: Then why don't you post your code with your attempt at using semaphores ? You of course need to 1/ make sure you release the lock and 2/ if the resource is already locked, wait until the lock is released.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers edited my post ,yes i released it once it is processed .

Comment: Ok, three issues here. First one, wsgi apps are typically deployed as multiple concurrent processes, so threading (which only affects the current process) won't work in production. You need a locking system that works for concurrent processes.  Second one: if you can't acquire the lock, you want to wait for it, not exit. And finally, when you get the lockyou want to make sure you _always_ release the lock _whatever happens_ - here you're not releasing it if an exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a mget method and set a time threshold. In this way you don't send one request for time but you send a request with a list of ids - doc [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-multi-get.html)

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import helpers    

idL = [] # create it before the flask route declaration
threshold = 5 #set a threshold in the same way
now = datetime.now()
delta = timedelta(seconds=30) # set a time threshold of 1 minute

def update(result):
    for success, info in helpers.parallel_bulk(client= es, actions=createUpdateElem(result ):
        if not success:
            print(info)
def index(result):
    for success, info in helpers.parallel_bulk(client= es, actions=createIndexElem(result ):
        if not success:
            print(info)

def createIndexElem(result):
     for elem in result:
         yield {
           '_op_type': 'index',
           '_index': 'database',
           '_id': elem,
           '_source': {'question': 'The life, universe and everything.'}
          }


def createUpdateElem(result):
    for elem in result:
         yield {
           '_op_type': 'update',
           '_index': 'database',
           '_id': elem,
           'doc': {'question': 'The life, universe and everything.'}
          }


def checkResponse(response, idL):
    updateL = []
    for elem in response['docs']:
        if elem['_id'] in idL:
            updateL.append(elem['_id'])
    toBeIndexed = list(set(idL) - set(updateL))
    return toBeIndexed,updateL




def multiget(idL):        
     response = es.mget(index = 'database',body = {'ids': idL})
     doc2BeIndicized = checkResponse(response, idL)
     now = datetime.now()
     idL = []
     return doc2BeIndicized


 @app.route('/test',methods=['POST'])
 def hello():       
    try:  

id  = request.form['id']
idL.append(id)
if len(idL) > threshold:
    result = multiget(idL)
    if result:
        indexed, updated = result
        if updated:
            update(updated)
        if indexed:
            index(indexed)
elif (now + delta) > datetime.now():
    result = multiget(idL)
    if result:
        indexed, updated = result
        if updated:
            update(updated)
        if indexed:
            index(indexed)
else:
     continue
```

In the same way you could index or update a list of document with bulk - or parallel bulk that is better in a service because it uses multithread. doc [here](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html) . Remember that you need to parse the response of mget call because in a list it is possible that only certain elements are presents in es and others not

Comment: what is now + delta delta here ??

Comment: now is defined or at the start of python script, or after a new update/indicization. I create a time delta of 30 seconds and then I check if var now + 30 is less than actual time. So it indicizes only 1 time in 30 seconds if there is less documents than then threshold number

Comment: sorry I have changed my var name, it wasn't delta. I correct now

Comment: Yes i corrected it but now im facing this error : unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'

Comment: Its not inserted into index,getting document missing error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209358/discussion-between-gomathi-meena-and-lupanoide).